# Building a water fountain with an  arduino

Tags: arduino

I am working on arduino project to make water fountain.The idea of fountain is given in the link: [Example of fountain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wldl_voZjoA&feature=endscreen&NR=1). Further, I am thinking to  modify it by rotating the base with the help of full rotation servo motor, but I have tried several number of times to run servo motor with arduino and its not working. However, half rotation servo motor is easily running. Can you please help me with this?

Moreover, I also want to know how dc water pump can be used to give pressure to water.

Comment: Please add your code. You cannot expect us to write your program for you. If you have a specific issue with a specific piece of code, I'm sure we can help you out!

Comment: Although this question is a terrible fit for SO, I can't help but thinking what an awesome idea it is! How did you get on with it?

Answer (score 1):

A DC water pump? Unless you have a 5v pump that would work you'll need to get one with a AC adapter (so you can plug it into a normal plug) and do something like [this article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tweet-a-Pot-Twitter-Enabled-Coffee-Pot/#step1). I know it's a coffee maker and with Twitter but it'll tell you how to control a normal device that you can plug in. With the full rotation servo you need to treat it like a normal servo and give it a degree with the servo library. (You might need to download it on [Arduino's website](http://arduino.cc)) Then you need to set it to roughly 90 degrees to stop, 180 to go forward full speed, and 0 to go full speed backwords. (The 90 degrees may be 85, 92, etc.) If you want it slower go inbetween stop and full speed.

With the servo make sure it's 5v also- if it's 9v connect the positive to the Arduino's VIN, ground to ground, and signal to whatever pin you choose. If it's 9v don't forget to plug in a 9v wall adapter to the barrel jack and switch power sources if you have to on your model. (The vin is whatever input you put in; If you put in a 9v adapter the VIN pin would be 9 volts but the 5v pin and the 3.3 volt pin would stay the same. VIN is make to hook up like a 9v battery if you don't have a barrel jack adapter and that's why there is two grounds on the same side.)

Hope this helps and good luck.